# Is there a groovyws.jar with all his dependences?

Tags: grails, groovy, groovyws

I'm using Grails and want to use groovyws to call an web-service.

But my groovyws.jar (0.5.2) have MANY dependences that I can't solve.

Is there any jar with all dependences included?

Note: I tried put in `BuildConfig.groovy`, this

```
dependencies {
'org.codehaus.groovy.modules:groovyws:0.5.2'
}
```

but I'm getting error:

> Error executing script Compile: loader constraint violation: when
>   resolving overridden method
>   "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.getParser()Lorg/xml/sax/Parser;"
>   the class loader (instance of
>   org/codehaus/groovy/grails/cli/support/GrailsRootLoader) of the
>   current class, org/apache/xerces/jaxp/SAXParserImpl, and its
>   superclass loader (instance of ), have different Class
>   objects for the type org/xml/sax/Parser used in the signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found:

- http://docs.codehaus.org/dosearchsite.action?queryString=groovyws+standalone

Tks a lot!

(search for "groovyws standalone")

Note: I saw this tip [here](http://www.grailsbrasil.com.br/post/show/591).

Comment: find 5.0 file here and was able to use with groovy 1.6.3 http://dist.codehaus.org/gmod/

Answer (score 1):

You can manually exclude xerces by:

```
dependencies {
    runtime('org.codehaus.groovy.modules:groovyws:0.5.2') {
        exclude: 'xerces'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GroovyWS pulls inn CXF, which again pulls in a lot of dependencies, some of them conflicting with classes already present in Java 6. You need to exclude all these dependencies if using Java 6, to avoid errors like the one you mention.

Here's my exclude list:

```
compile("org.codehaus.groovy.modules:groovyws:0.5.2") {
    excludes 'geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec', 'servlet-api', 'jaxb-xjc', 'jaxb-impl', 'xml-apis', 'saaj-impl', 'junit', 'slf4j-jdk14', 'xmlParserAPIs', 'jaxb-api', 'saaj-api', 'xmlbeans', 'jaxen', 'geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec', 'geronimo-activation_1.0.2_spec', 'abdera-client', 'geronimo-activation_1.1_spec'
}
```

Note that on Ubuntu you need jaxb-xjc and jaxb-impl after all, don't know why.