# Grails: I can't use ws-client plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, ws-client

I'm using grails 1.3.6 and installed ws-client plugin.

I getting error in the following hello world:

```
def wsdlURL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL"
def proxy = webService.getClient(wsdlURL)
def result = proxy.CelsiusToFahrenheit(0)
result = "${result} degrees Farhenheit"
render result
```

Error:

> Could not initialize class
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl

But I have this class (Ctrl+Shift+T in STS find the class)

Thanks.

Related question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748383/is-there-a-groovyws-jar-with-all-his-dependences)

Comment: what other plugins do you have installed?

Comment: gsolr, codenarc 0.7, hibernate 1.3.6 and tomcat 1.3.6

Comment: don't know gsolr, does it embed xerces? Xerces is a well known candidate for causing problems. General approach is to exclude the dependency to xerces(Impl) in BuildConfig.groovy. Check if xerces show up in output of 'grails dependency-report'

Comment: SOLVED! I removed gsolr and works! Tks a lot Stefan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed another plugin (gsolr) that had conflicts and works.

Note: another solution is create a plugin project to wrap ws-client plugin.
(I this way there is no conflict beetween classes)